# How to optimize the generation of a pdf from a html with a lot of images

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using KnpLabs/snappy to generate a pdf of a catalogue from a html page which has a lot of images (and they'll keep growing). 
It semt to be ok but now it takes a lot of time to generate the pdf and often it shows this error:

```
Type: Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException
Message: The process "vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --margin-bottom '0px' --margin-left '0px' --margin-right '0px' --margin-top '0px' --no-outline --allow 'images' --allow 'css' --disable-javascript --footer-html '/tmp/knp_snappy56e83aa6113ee0.03470261.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy56e83aa6112b04.32650882.html' 'catalogues/56e83aa61115e.pdf'" exce
```

eded the timeout of 60 seconds.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: reduce the amount of processing required, or increase the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of tiny images then you can convert the image to base64 and then process it to display images

**Note:** On converting the image to base64 the size of image will increase but the time of loading the image from the server will become 0 because now the image is a part of html page only

Comment: I don't think the problem is fetching the images, I guess the process of getting them on pdf is the issue

Comment: I remember when i used wkhtmltopdf for coverting html pages  to pdf ...images werent getting into pdf so i converted those images into base64 and then they started displaying in pdf

Comment: When I create a softer version of the pdf (with just 20 images) it works fine, do you think it might help? I'll try anyway